Inverse of squares of fractional ideals
I am thinking about the following problem:
Given a fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ in the Dedekind domain $R$ with field of fractions $K$, its inverse is defined to be $\mathfrak{a}^{-1} = \lbrace x \in K \,\mid \, x\mathfrak{a} \subseteq R \rbrace $. Thus, by definition, $\mathfrak{a}^{-2} = \lbrace x \in K \,\mid \, x\mathfrak{a}^2 \subseteq R \rbrace $.
But what about the set $S = \lbrace x \in K \, \mid \, a^2x \in R, \text{ for all }a \in \mathfrak{a} \rbrace$? It is easily seen to be an $R$-submodule of $K$, so it is itself a fractional ideal and it also contains $\mathfrak{a}^{-2}$.
Is there an easy criterion to decide when the equality $S = \mathfrak{a}^{-2}$ holds? And what can be said about the integral ideal $S^{-1}\mathfrak{a}^{-2}$?

The ideal $\mathfrak a^2$ is generally not the ideal generated by the squares $a^2$ where $a \in \mathfrak a$: it is the ideal generated by all $aa'$ where $a$ and $a'$ are in $\mathfrak a$.
Let $J$ be the ideal generated by all $a^2$ with $a \in \mathfrak a$. Since each $a^2$ is in $\mathfrak a^2$ and $\mathfrak a^2$ is an ideal, $J \subset \mathfrak a^2$.
Since $J$ is generated as an $R$-module by all $a^2$ where $a \in \mathfrak a$, your set $S$ is $J^{-1}$.  So the condition $S = \mathfrak a^{-2}$ is equivalent to $J^{-1} = \mathfrak a^{-2}$, which is equivalent to $J = \mathfrak a^2$. Thus $S = \mathfrak a^{-2}$ exactly when $\mathfrak a^2$ is generated by $a^2$ for all $a \in \mathfrak a$.
